# Joining columns when any match

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two tables/dataframes based on some conditions.

For example in one table I have a column `name`

In the other table I have the columns `name1`, `name2`, `name3`

How do I join the tables on the columns, when any of the name columns in the second table matches, and use the columns in the order of `name` `name2` `name3` to join when possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `join` that takes an expression as the conditional algorithm and use the `or` (||)

```
df1.join(df2, $"name" === $"name1" || $"name" === $"name2" || $"name" === $"name3")
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without explicitly writing out each column name?

Comment: Not that I can think of. How else would it know which maps to which?

Comment: I mean assuming the column names are the same in both tables, is there some simple way to join when any of the columns match?

Comment: @Ted Not to my knowledge